# Invalid exhaustive deps in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using a react hook to fetch the data from covid api using axios but it throws an error of

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'countries'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

where countries is my state

Code:

```
const [countries,setCountries]=useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries').then(response=>{
      //console.log(response.data);
      setCountries(response.data);
      console.log(countries);
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    })

  },[]);
```

I have tried doing every solutions provided by other forums but this is prefectly fine mentioned by some solutions. Why isnt this code working?

Comment: Don't log `countries` after calling `setCountries()`. That's why the `useEffect()` is requiring it as a dependency.

Comment: The error describes what's wrong. You use `countries` (a state value) inside `useEffect` without declaring it as a dependency (`useEffect(()=>{/*...*/}, [countries]);`). So, as PatricRoberts commented, remove the `console.log`. It would yield *stale* data anyway.

Comment: @Yoshi you shouldn't declare it as a dependency or the side-effect will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: if i do that the log appears in an infinite loop but i want it to happen only when the page refreshes

Comment: Also worth noting the value of `countries` won't update within the hook, so you'll get the "old" value of `countries` if you log it there anyway. To see the new data there you'll need to log `response.data`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts True, that would then be the next question. I wanted to focus on how the error perfectly describes what's wrong.

Comment: thanks the problem was cosoling countries inside it, took me an hour to figure out lol i am a newbie to react so anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use `countries` in your hook, you should add it to your deps. Otherwise you will read a stale value because the state value `countries` was not yet updated:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries').then(response=>{
      //console.log(response.data);
      setCountries(response.data);
      console.log(countries);
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  },[countries]);
```

However in your case **I would advice against adding `countries` to your deps**, because you also call `setCountries` in your hook. This way your hook would be entered again because `countries` has changed.
You should rather log the value of countries outside of your hook if you need it.

```
console.log(countries);

useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries').then(response=>{
      //console.log(response.data);
      setCountries(response.data);
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  },[]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are adding any variables which can be changed in useEffect it will ask you to update the dependency array.You are logging countries that's why you are seeing this warning.

If you want to understand useEffect in depth, and about the dependency array blog by Dan Abramov about [A complete Guide To Useeffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) will be very helpful